# Requeue or evaluate delayed job from inside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Is there a way to determine the status of a running [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) job from inside the job task itself? I have a job that interacts with a service that can be pretty flaky and for a certain class of connection failures I'd like to requeue the job and only raise an exception if a connection failure occurs again at the retry limit.

Pseudo-code to demonstrate what I want to be able to do:

```
def do_thing
  service.send_stuff(args)
rescue Exception1, Exception2
  if job.retries == JOBS_MAX
    raise
  else
    job.requeue
  end
end
```

I don't want to raise an exception on any failure because generally the job will be completed okay on a later retry and it is just making noise for me. I *do* want to know if it is never completed, though.

Comment: Doesn't DJ automatically requeue a job after failure?

Comment: Yes but the only way I know to cause a failure-based requeue is to raise an exception - which I will get notified about. I only want that to happen on the last retry attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, if the Delayed Job runner gets to the end of the `perform` queue then it will be considered as a successful run and removed from the queue. So you just have to stop it from getting to the end. There isn't a requeue -- even if there was it'd be a new record with new attributes. So you may rethink whatever it is that is causing the job to notify you about exceptions. You could, for example, add a condition upon which to notify you...

**Potential Solutions**

You can get the default `JOBS_MAX` (as you pseudo-coded it) with `Delayed::Worker.max_attempts` or you can set your own per-job by defining a method, e.g.: `max_attempts`.

```
# Fail permanently after the 10th failure for this job
def max_attempts
  10
end
```

That is, this method will be usable given the following:

You can also make use of [callback hooks](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks). Delayed Job will callback to your payload object via the `error` method if it is defined. So you may be able to use the `error` method to notify you of actual exceptions beyond a given attempt number. To do that...

Within the callback, the Delayed::Job object itself is returned as the first argument:

```
def error(job, exception)
  job.attempts # gives you the current attempt number
  # If job.attempts is greater than max_attempts then send exception notification
  # or whatever you want here...
end
```

So you can use the callbacks to start adding logic on when to notify yourself and when not to. I might even suggest making a base set of functionality that you can include into all of your payload objects to do these things... but that's up to you and your design.

Answer (score 3):

Define a custom job for DJ, setting a number for `max_attempts` and behavior for the `error` callback. This is untested, but it might look something like this:

```
class DoThingJob

  def max_attempts; @max_attempts ||= 5; end

  def error(job, exception)
    case exception
    when Exception1, Exception2
      # will be requeued automatically until max_attempts is reached
      # can add extra log message here if desired
    else
      @max_attempts = job.attempts
      # this will cause DJ to fail the job and not try again
    end
  end

end
```

**NOTE**

I started writing this before @pdobb posted his answer. I'm posting it anyway because it provides some more detail about how you might handle the exceptions and requeue logic.