# How to prevent DelayedJob from re-queuing for certain exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, delayed-job

We have a delayed_job class that gets unprocessable responses for certain API requests. The responses aren't going to change, so there is no point in re-queuing the job when it fails. However we still want to reqeue other failures, just not this one.

I can avoid the re-queue by capture the exception in `perform`, but then the failure is not even logged. I would like to have it logged as an error, not as a success.

It seems to me there would be a way to indicate certain exception classes as being exempt from re-queuing - is there?

I thought of using the `error` hook to simply delete the job, but my guess would be that something would explode if the job disappeared out from under DJ while it was processing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766321/requeue-or-evaluate-delayed-job-from-inside

Comment: I did, but I did not get as far as the part with a dynamic max_attempts callback. Very clever, looks like it will work. Thanks!

Comment: @apod - would you like to repost that in an answer so I can give you credit for answering the question?

Comment: It won't let me write that as an answer since it's just a link to another post. No worries!